# Фиксированный фон на мобильном

Tags: css, css3

Сделал фоновое изображения таким способом, работает.

```css
body{
position: relative;
min-height: 200vh
}
body:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: -10;
        background: url(https://news.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/news/photos/000/755/75552.jpg) no-repeat center center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

НО когда начинаешь скроллить страницу на мобильно , изображения дергается,
из-за того что адресная строка браузера уезжает вверх .
Как сделать чтобы изображения не дергалось?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А нормально делать через background не катит?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить свойства для body(проверил на iphone 5s)

```
body {
   position: relative;
   min-height: 200vh
   margin:0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: В проекте на котором я пытаюсь это сделать, уже указаны эти свойства, не работает

Comment: ну это уже совсем другой вопрос и задача)

Comment: всегда интересовал вопрос зачем люди насилуют body, не проще использовать контейнер под нужды. body вообще плохо реагирует на свойства position и может повести себя не предсказуемо, так как это основная видимая часть документа